# I've Encountered a Segmentation Error Fortran on Reading Data Files from an Outside source

Tags: fortran, file-read

I've been writing a program that reads an integer value from a file using the OPEN statement and prints the value on the console.

During the compiling, it seems to be okay and got no problems, but when I run the program, I've encountered a segmentation fault.

I've reviewed the code and so far I haven't violated any rules. Can someone to give me an idea about this problem?

Error:

[image]

Code:

```
program project5_03
implicit none 
integer :: n = 0
open ( unit = 21, file = 'trial.txt', status = 'old')
read (21,*) n
print '(1x,a,i4)', "this is the value of n", n
stop
end program
```

The content of the txt file is just the number "1234" on the first line.

Comment: It is quite essential to show how do you compile the code. The backtrace is very suspicious, it would be more useful with `-g -fbacktrace` or similar.

Comment: have you successfuly compiled and run even simpler codes?

Comment: Please use the `newunit` specifier in your `open` statement. Hard-coding file identification units is incredibly error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, the code should work. It would have been nice if you had actually given us the compiler version and -options as well.
I mean there is the thing that you're not closing the file that you've opened, but since the program terminates anyway, it shouldn't be much of an issue.

What I'd do is use the error status and -message variables, something like this:

```
program project5_03
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    integer :: ios
    character(len=200) :: iomsg
    open (unit=21, file='trial.txt', status='old', iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg)
    call check(ios, iomsg, "OPEN")
    read (21,*, iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg) n
    call check(ios, iomsg, "READ n")
    write(*,'(1x,a,i4)', iostat=ios, iomsg=iomsg), "this is the value of n", n
    call check(ios, iomsg, "WRITE to STDOUT")
    stop
contains
    subroutine check(ios, iomsg, op)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: ios
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: iomsg, op
        if (ios == 0) return
        print*, "Encountered Error ", ios, " during ", op
        print*, iomsg
        stop
    end subroutine check
end program
```

Maybe this will help you find the bug.

There is also the fact that you use `integer :: n = 0` -- which should not be a problem with the main program, but in subroutines this implies the `SAVE` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able fix this by changing my Compiler as suggested by the Fortran expert in the facebook. :)    I have to change from TDM gfortran to Cygwin based fortran.... Thanks